# Is it a little bit redundant to say "These include games such as"?

Tags: word-usage

[According to Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/include)

> Symptoms of the illness include a high temperature and a persistent dry cough.

Which uses the pattern `A include A_1 and A_2`.

Similarly, [a wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_sport) uses the same pattern.

> Common combat sports **include** mixed martial arts, boxing ...

However, [another wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_game) seems a little bit redundant.

> Ball games (or ballgames), also ball sports, are any form of game or sport which feature a ball as part of play. These **include games such as** football, cricket ...

Is it a little bit redundant to say "These include games such as"?

Answer (score 1):

Your example,

> These include games such as football, cricket ...

would be mildly redundant if the subject was clearly games.  But it might not be if the subject was something related but not precisely games.

For example, suppose, the subject was Sports, e.g.

> Sports are physical activities involving known rules and usually competition.
> These would include games such as football, cricket, ...

In this case the word games provides information, and could be understood to imply that some sports are games, but some sports are not games.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please give some sports that are not games?

Comment: @PutBere Cycling, swimming, diving, track & field events, skiing, archery, ...

Answer (score 0):

Basically what BTC said. The wiki page is redundant. If you have already prefaced the subject you are talking about you not need reiterate the topic you’re talking about.  However, this will always vary based on a number of variables that are too exhausting to list.

Comment: Thank you. Considering the sentence before `these`, "Ball games (or ballgames), also ball sports, are any form of game or sport which feature a ball as part of play." Have I already prefaced the subject I'm talking about? If yes, what the subject is?